# Adding a MAXSLOT method to training

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Im making an application where an user can book a hour of training. I want to give the app the restriction of when a training has 24 users booked nobody cant book anymore (at least some user delete his book), my question is how can i implement this function MAXSLOT in training model  and how i can put it to work

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
    @booking.training_id
  end

  def create
    @booking = @training.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Book created"
      redirect_to trainings_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end


  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Book deleted"
    redirect_to trainings_path
  end



private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :training_id)
  end

  def load_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  end

end
```

Booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true



end
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
  resources :users
end
```

Training model:

```
class Training < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings

end
```

Trainings controller:

```
class TrainingsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @training = Training.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @trainings = Training.all
  end
end
```

Index of training view:

```
<h1>Hours</h1>

<ul class="trainings">
  <% @trainings.each do |training| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to training.hour, training_path(training) %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Show of training view:

```
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/index_bookings' if logged_in? %>
  </center>
```

This is my squema.rb:

```
  create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "training_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["training_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_training_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "trainings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "slots"
    t.text     "hour"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["hour"], name: "index_trainings_on_hour"
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this. I'd recommend something like this:

```
# Training
class Training < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
  has_many :bookings

  # Check if anymore bookings can be added
  def can_book?
    bookings.count < slots # Depending on the exact logic of your app, it might make more sense to use users.count here instead. Your call.
  end
end

# Booking
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true

  # It might make sense to only validate this on create. Get rid of the `#` on the below line if you think so.
  validate :training_not_full?#, on: :create

  private

  def training_not_full?
    errors.add(:training, "The training session is full!") unless training.can_book?
  end
end
```

When you get to the `if @booking.save` in the controller, `@booking.valid?` is automatically called. If that returns false, then `@booking.save` will not save the record, and will also return false. This way, you can control persistence logic through your own validations in the models. The controller logic doesn't need to change at all.

I recommend reading about rails validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). Skip to 6.2 for the relevant section.

Also, as a word of warning, `default_scope`s usually wind up doing more harm then good. Eventually you'll have a use case where you'll want to order by something else, and you'll find yourself working around the scope pretty often. You'll probably save yourself some headaches down the line if you get rid of it now.

Comment: shouldnt i have to associate somehow the can_book? with the training.slots? in the training model

Comment: What is training.slots, exactly?

Comment: Its the attribute of how many slots the training has, i updated the post with squema.rb so you can see better what i mean. I think i have to associate somehow the method with training.slots so when training.slots gets to a certain number it will stop making books. I dont know if im wrong, just guessing

Comment: I'm confused, you say at the top of your question that a training can have a max of 24 slots. Does this mean that different trainings can have a different number of max slots? Or is training.slots the of _remaining_ slots?

Comment: I would like the option to change the max slots at some time, sorry for confusing you

Comment: No problem, in that case it's easy. Just get rid of the `MAX_SLOTS = 24` in my above answer, and replace the reference to it in `can_book?` with `slots`. Updated again. (Also I think I had a `>` when I should have had a `<`. Fixed that too.)

Comment: Okay so its supposed that when i do this it doesnt let me book more than training.slots right?

Comment: Correct. If a training record has as many bookings as is the value in its `slots` column, then when you try to save a new booking, it will fail.

Comment: btw the   validate :training_not_full?#, on: :create should not be validateS?

Comment: Correct. There is an example in the documentation I linked to that uses `validate` instead of `validates`. See section 6.2 in that link. "validate" and "validates" work slightly differently. The details are in that documentation.

Comment: It worked!!! Now im trying to figure out how to send the message the errors.add method didnt worked. Thanks tho!!! God bless you bro

Comment: hey bro i couldnt find why the error doesnt show when the training is full. do you think i have to add the gem jquery?

Comment: You probably don't need jQuery for this. If the `#create` method fails to save, it renders the `new` template, right? What does the new template look like, and does it have anything to render the errors? If there's already something like `<%= flash[:errors] %>` in the new template, then just make sure to set the flash value in the controller in the else statement before the `render 'new'`. This comment chain is getting pretty long. I would suggest opening this as a new question if the problem persists.